# Django Allauth Error Using default_token_generator

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm trying to generate a default token to send a reset password email but when the code runs **default_token_generator.make_token(user)** the user has no **last_login** property. What am I doing wrong here?

AttributeError at /devices/0/forgot
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'last_login'

```
            user = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email)
            if Provision.objects.get(device=device, user=user):
                # email_address = EmailAddress.objects.get_primary(user=user)
                token = default_token_generator.make_token(user) ...
                site = Site.objects.get_current()
                # send the password reset email
                path = reverse("account_reset_password_from_key", kwargs=dict(uidb36=int_to_base36(user.pk), key=token))
                url = '%s://%s%s' % (app_settings.DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL, site.domain, path)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `user = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email)` - `filter()` returns QuerySet, `make_token()` expects User model instance. Try `user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=email)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES section provide

```
django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
```

is listed, as this is what provides Django user with this property, so the resulting MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is something like

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: thanks dmitryro, the previous answer fixed the problem.